# List all augmentations of an object

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

Assumed I've augmented the native Object `Number` by the method `integer`:

```
Number.prototype.integer = function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
}

console.log ((-10/3).integer());
```

And other team members have added some methods too. How can I list all the subsequent augmentations? How can I list all the existing methods, also the nativ-ones?

**EDIT:** It is only about listing of augmentations of an object, nothing more,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Obect.keys` to get an array of all the keys of the prototype of the class you augmented.

```
var augmentedProperties = Object.keys(Number.prototype);
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
Number.prototype.integer = function(){/**/};
Number.prototype.float = function(){/**/};
Number.prototype.something = function(){/**/};

var augmentedProperties = Object.keys(Number.prototype);

console.log("Augmented properties: ", augmentedProperties);
```

Comment: How can I list all the existing methods? (Also the nativ-ones,..)

Comment: @Lonely `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number.prototype)` will get all the properties (including those augmented). `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number)` will get the propreties of the object `Number` itself (not the ones included in the prototype because here `prototype` is one of the properties too).

Comment: @Lonely but as mentioned in the comment: It's not a good practice to modify Native Objects (unles you're taking very good care).

Comment: thank you, but that's not the point, it is about listing of methods, nativ-ones, and augmented-ones, as I wrote in the title and edited in the question,.. Your answer is absolutely OK!